# Sorting strings in a list based upon arbitrary numbers in the middle of the strings

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list

```
a = ['d2da1.png','d2da11.png','d2da2.png','d2da111.png','d2da22.png']
```

that I want to automatically sort based upon the last number before the period, `.` in each element. This number in the string may be any integer of any length (e.g. `1`,`11`,`2`,`111`,`22`).  The output sought is

```
a = ['d2da1.png','d2da2.png','d2da11.png','d2da22.png','d2da111.png']
```

Conventional methods such as `sorted` fail here, and brute forcing may be time-intensive if considering very large lists. Therefore, is there a way to sort the strings above based upon the last full number in the string to output the sought list?

Comment: Is the "prefix" before the number to be sorted the same in all file name?  It appears to be in your example or are the prefixes diverse?

Comment: There is a module, [natsort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort/18415320#18415320) that sorts in the order you need.

Comment: @JeffH The prefix is arbitrary, but for a particular list, it would be constant (e.g. fixed to `'d2da'` for the above list).

Comment: OK.  Well, my answer stands below.  :).  You have several options here.  Each might have problems if the prefix portion has additional digits in it, or if some do/some don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefix/suffix remains the same, this works and I think is pretty clear:

```
In [10]: a                                                                      
Out[10]: ['d2da1.png', 'd2da11.png', 'd2da2.png', 'd2da111.png', 'd2da22.png']

In [11]: def chop(s): 
    ...:     return int(s.replace('d2da','').replace('.png','')) 
    ...:                                                                        

In [12]:                                                                        

In [12]: [chop(t) for t in a]    # a little side-test on chop()                                                  
Out[12]: [1, 11, 2, 111, 22]

In [13]: a.sort(key=lambda x: chop(x))                                          

In [14]: a                                                                      
Out[14]: ['d2da1.png', 'd2da2.png', 'd2da11.png', 'd2da22.png', 'd2da111.png']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

a = ['d2da1.png','d2da11.png','d2da2.png','d2da111.png','d2da22.png']

a.sort(key=lambda x : int(re.search(r'(\d+)\.', x).group(1)))
print(a)
# ['d2da1.png', 'd2da2.png', 'd2da11.png', 'd2da22.png', 'd2da111.png']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an implementation of `itertools.takewhile` combo with `sorted`:

```
import itertools as it
sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(''.join(it.takewhile(str.isdigit, x[-5:0:-1]))[::-1]))
```

Result:

```
['d2da1.png', 'd2da2.png', 'd2da11.png', 'd2da22.png', 'd2da111.png']
```

`takewhile` will grab the digits from `.` in reverse.
`''.join` to form the string and `[::-1]` to reverse it back, and convert to `int`.
Use that as the `sort` key and it'll produce the desired result.